# How do I save a file in the data folder of another app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an application which I want to save a file 'xxname' to the data folder of another application, the file is saved in the data folder of my application but how I move it from that folder.

Example: 
From: var/mobile/containers/data/application/myApp/Documents 
To: var/mobile/containers/data/application/OtherApp/Documents/bin

Thanks

Comment: You can't save it directly due to the sandbox. You can look at `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller` or creating a share extension or using an app group,if you are creating both apps. Any solution will require support for what you are trying to do from the second app

Comment: Exchange data with iCloud.